# Accessing \\localhost in windows 7

Tags: windows-explorer, connection, localhost

Problem is:
I cannot access **\localhost** from my **system explorer**(C:\Windows\explorer.exe);
I cannot access any other web resource in file explorer,
error is always the same generic "0x80004005";

Network card ip is set to DHCP;
Windows firewall is down;
Network sharing is enabled on all the Lan types.
Sared folders in my system have all the same security: everyone.

SO: Win 7 pro x64;
PC model : Fujitsu Lifebook A544;

Steps done: 
use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost,
use win+R to run \localhost;
try to use fixed IP.

So, why I'm not able to access even my own pc, and the local shared folders?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned in which port localhost is installed. If localhost is installed in any other port Try: `http://localhost:PortNumber/`. Check if NetBIOS service is running. If doesn't run then start it using `net start imhosts` in cmd. If your network connection is using IPv4 then disable IPv6. To do this modify registry key

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\DisabledComponents` to 0x20   [1]

Reference: [1]:https://serverfault.com/questions/218745/disable-ipv6-on-loopback-address-localhost-computer-name